# android using viewholder out of bindview()

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a class that extends `CursorAdapter()` class. There is an Overriden `bindView()` which has -

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```

I need to use this `viewHolder` outside of `bindView()` method meaning in my own method but in the same class. How do I do that?

The `bindView()` method is `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but the simplest way to achieve what you're looking for is to just pass a `ViewHolder` instance as a parameter:

```
private void someMethod(ViewHolder holder) {}
```

Comment: Please see this post of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130505/android-how-to-use-viewholder-to-set-text-out-of-bindview-in-cursoradapter-cla

I have to use viewholder to set textview in setArrivalTime() method

Comment: @Samuel909 question no longer there. :|